# Plugin call when virtuemart order done

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

i create one new component and for that i want virtuemart order id when virtuemart complete the order.

my component and virtuemart component is different so i think need to create plugin. but i dont want to write code in virtuemart component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a plugin that is also needs to call from VM files.
When the Order has been placed that time VM calling Order.php model file and cart helper.php

so you should be call function to your component or plugin call that code should in any of the  above page.

for more details you can check the payment or shipment plugin that VM Provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think this extension will helpful for you, but this is connect with vtiger integration

[Click Here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/crm-bridges/21208)